# GCC inlining failed in call to always_inline

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors

I am obtaining this error while a compiling (with GCC) an external library whose code I am not authorized to modify:

`error: inlining failed in call to always_inline`

Is there any argument I may pass to GCC to force it to ignore the attribute:  `__attribute__((always_inline))`

Comment: `-Dalways_inline=someothersafeattribute`. May break other stuff though.

Comment: Thank you. It solved my problem.

Comment: @MarcGlisse What exactly are the reasons for this error?

Comment: @pushpen.paul That's a different question, you should create a new question, include a [mcve], and someone may be able to explain why you are getting this error in your particular case.

Comment: Usually you get this from trying to compile AVX intrinsics without AVX enabled, or similar.  (Look at the end of the error: in that case it will say `target specific option mismatch`)